# jquery resizable issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize-image

Here is my code:

```
$('#resize').click(function() {
    $('#test').resizable();
});
```

When I click the `resize` div, i want the `test` div to be resizable. But the test div in this case is not becoming resizable. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: After you click on the `resize` element, take a look in firebug and see if the `test` element gets a new class added to it by jQuery. That will narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @david--the ui-resizeable classes do get added. but i am still not able to resize the div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED.

I had not included a custom css file. Thats why the icons for the resize handles were not showing up. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jQuery UI script is attached as well as your standard jQuery. The resizeable() function is exclusive to jQuery UI & does not come standard.

Please post Javascript console errors if there are any.